# Cakephp 3.6 - Save using a database function

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to save a file into the database using a PostgreSQL function(pgp_pub_encrypt_bytea) to encrypt the file.

The problem is that the function gets parsed as text in the resulting query.
This is the data array:

```
$file_base64= base64_encode(file_get_contents($file['file']['tmp_name']));

$data = [
    'some_id' => $some_id,
    'name' => $file['file']['name'],
    'mime' => $file['file']['type'],
    'code'=> $code,
    'file' => "pgp_pub_encrypt_bytea(decode('$file_base64', 'base64'), dearmor('$pgp_public_key'))" 
];
```

Now in the debug_kit this is the resulting query:

```
INSERT INTO file_table (
  some_id, name, mime, code, file
) 
VALUES 
  (
    26, '1.png', 'image/png', '07e24948c82a2d7b758266d84e8464a23904cf90a78dfb', 
    'pgp_pub_encrypt_bytea(decode(''<-- HERE IS THE FILE IN BASE64 TEXT -->'', ''base64''), dearmor(''<-- HERE IS THE PGP KEY -->''))'
  ) RETURNING *
```

So you see this is the line that is passed as text:

> 'pgp_pub_encrypt_bytea(decode(''<-- HERE IS THE FILE IN BASE64 TEXT
>   -->'', ''base64''), dearmor(''<-- HERE IS THE PGP KEY -->''))'

But I need to execute it as the function- how can I do this?

---

**SOLUTION**:

I managed to find my own answer, went to cakephp documentarion and read carefully the "Using SQL functions":

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions

And changed my data array to this:

```
$data = [
    'some_id' => $some_id,
    'name' => $file['file']['name'],
    'mime' => $file['file']['type'],
    'code'=> $code,
    'file' => $table->query()->func()->pgp_pub_encrypt_bytea(["decode('$file_base64', 'base64'), dearmor('$pgp_public_key')" => 'literal']) 
];
```

> $table->query()->func()->pgp_pub_encrypt_bytea()

Means i want to add a function to the query called pgp_pub_encrypt_bytea.

Then the content in the function that we want to execute literally:

> ["decode('$file_base64', 'base64'), dearmor('$pgp_public_key')" =>
>   'literal']

That fixed my problem =D

Comment: please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you :)